# What type of images should be candidate for CSS sprites?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, css-sprites

I have lot of images in the project of type .png,.gif,.jpg which also vary by height and width. I want to implement the CSSSprites for all the images present in the project by using the following article:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek1ASPNETSpriteAndImageOptimization.aspx

Can anyone help me to know what kind of images should be included as part of the CSS Sprites.

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 0):

You can include any kind of images in a sprite including logos, icons, static thumbnails etc, just avoid adding big info-graphics.